# Onclick of Image (used in element <a>) not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this footer of a fixed nav-bar in Div.

```
<div id="footer">
    <div class="col-xs-12 navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <div class="row" id="bottomNav">
            <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                <a id="id1" href="#">
                    <img id="image1" src='img/feature1.png' alt='missing'>
                    <div class="caption">Act-1</div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                <a id="id2" href="#">
                    <img id="image2" src='img/feature2.png' alt='missing'>
                    <div class="caption">Act-2</div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                <a id="id3" href="#">
                    <img id="image3" src='img/feature3.png' alt='missing'>
                    <div class="caption">Act-3</div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

On click of image1, I want to do some stuff. I am using alert to test it. The jquery function is in a separate js file which is added in the html. This is the only function js file has in it. I tried to use #id1 and #image1 both in the ebelow function, but it just would not get called.

```
$("#image1").click(function() {
    alert("you are in Act-1 window");
});
```

what's wrong in such a simple code, i just can't get it.

Comment: try `$("#image1").on('click',function() {
    alert("you are in Act-1 window");
});`

Comment: @RahulNaik What does it change?

Comment: Please add css also, and make code snippet if possible

Comment: Check the network tab in chrome to see if the your js file is loading

Comment: Remove the anchor, and use CSS to style the "button".

Comment: This code works fine. Either the JS file is not loading at all, either you load it BEFORE the HTML is ready and loaded, or either some other error crashes your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine. It seems to be working for me. The alert gets called if that is what you are looking for

```js
$("#image1").click(function() {
    alert("you are in Act-1 window");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="footer">
    <div class="col-xs-12 navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <div class="row" id="bottomNav">
            <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                <a id="id1" href="#">
                    <img id="image1" src='img/feature1.png' alt='missing'>
                    <div class="caption">Act-1</div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                <a id="id2" href="#">
                    <img id="image2" src='img/feature2.png' alt='missing'>
                    <div class="caption">Act-2</div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                <a id="id3" href="#">
                    <img id="image3" src='img/feature3.png' alt='missing'>
                    <div class="caption">Act-3</div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But you're not solving the problem : if the code works for you, why is it not working for OP?

Comment: all that is different is i have a jquery script. I copied the snippet @JeremyThille

Comment: What a misery. I saw it working for @Sushil. So I deleted my html and recreated it, and it worked. This is as crazy as it can get and it took away 2 hrs of my time today.

Comment: Was it all just because you forgot to include jQuery?? If so, your console should just have told you. The console is your first friend.

Answer (score -1):

Why you put the image inside a href="#" if you are not going to use it? here you have the error

Answer (score -2):

You can also avoid jQuery by vanila js.

```
var img = document.querySelector('#YourID');
img.addEventListener('click', handler function);
```

It's better to use separated function for handling ( in this case you can remove the handler).

Comment: If jQuery doesn't work, rewriting the same code in pure JS won't work either. This doesn't solve the problem. Downvoted

Comment: Ok, I am agree about solving the problem. But I didn't understand why pure js doesn't work ??

Comment: Because the very same thing with jQuery doesn't work. Replacing it with vanillaJS won't solve the problem. If you hold a weapon backwards, you won't hit the target. If you change the weapon, you still won't hit the target. The problem is that you hold the weapon backwards.